# Detect window closing OCaml Graphics

Tags: events, window, ocaml

I haven't found details about window closing detection in the Graphics documentation. How detect it so I can trigger an action on closing ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple test program (included at the end of this answer) and closing the window manually tells us that the following exception is raised:

```
Fatal error: exception Graphics.Graphic_failure("fatal I/O error")
```

Which means that we can handle the window being closed by using an exception handler:

```
try
  (* Here goes the code opening and manipulating the window *)
with
  | Graphic_failure("fatal I/O error") ->
  (* Here goes the code handling the window being closed manually*)
```

Test program (you need to run `ocamlc graphics.cma test.ml -o test` to compile it):

```
open Graphics

let rec loop () = loop ()
let () =
(*
  try
*)
    Graphics.open_graph " 400x600";
    loop ()
(*
  with
    | Graphic_failure("fatal I/O error") ->
      print_string "Caught exception";
      print_newline ()
*)
```

Comment: For me it raises `Graphic_failure("Xlib error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)")`... Also my applications is has some graphics but is terminal controlled, sort of an interpreter, so I don't have a loop for event. I still have a loop for commands so I could catch exception after a command has been sent...
So a temporary solution is to match `Graphic_failure("fatal I/O error")` and `Graphic_failure("Xlib error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)")`, but how I could I know there aren't other exceptions I should catch ?

Comment: Even if I try to catch those exception in my main, it results in a fatal error.
I have surrounded the code that launch command (text and graphical ones) with a `try match` for the `Graphic_failure` above and it doesn't help.
I have also tried to match `Graphic_failure _` and it still doesn't help...